# Puppet 3.8.1 hanging on windows

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet 3.8.1 and running command line as a administrator but puppet is hanging.

With debug turned on I get too

```
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=3.8.1, ruby_version=2.0.0, run_mode=user, default_encodin
g=CP850
Debug: Loading external facts from C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/facts.d
```

and no further...

I'm using a helloworld manifest of

```
file { 'C:/_Tmp/puppettest/test.txt':
    content => "Hello, world\n",    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok... after 5-10mins it works! Why is it taking so long?

Comment: try running sysinternals procmon to see what its doing https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Not a clue, but definitely not desired

Comment: If you flip over to the v4 series puppet agent, what kind of results do you get?